# Trash can never shows as empty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cinnamon, trash

On Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.1, the desktop has a trash can icon. It always shows the icon that indicates there is something in it. There isn't. I have tried to empty the trash from the desktop, I have tried trash-empty, and I have done rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash . There's no trash, but the icon refuses to change. I have tried turning the icon off and on again.

This used to work as expected and I don't know what changed.

Comment: try it with `gio trash -f --empty trash`

Comment: No change, unfortunately.